# Code for Python as Prime and function

Tags: python

Stuck on this problem and I couldn't find an answer and my code keeps failing.

Write a function called specialPrime which takes in an integer as an argument and returns True if the integer is a prime number and length of the integer squared is less than six digits, False if it is not a prime number or the integer squared is greater than six digits. Write a program which prompts the user to type in an integer and uses you specialPrime function to determine whether or not the integer is special.

Example Interaction
Enter a number: 140
140 is not a special prime number.
Enter a number: 89
89 is a special prime number.

My code

```
def specialPrime(isPrime,G6):
isPrime= int(input('Enter a number:')
    if isPrime < 2 return False 
    elif isPrime == 2
        return True  
    for n in range(2, x)
        if x % n ==0:
        return False
    return True
G6 = len(isPrime**2)
    if G6 > 6: return False
    else
    return True
while True
print( isPrime + 'is a special number')
else
print( isPrime + 'is not a special prime')
```

`

Comment: At least as posted, nearly every line has a problem with it. You'll need to verify that the code as shown is as it is on your computer. If it is, there way too much wrong for it to be appropriate here.

Comment: You donot need declare G6 as input variable here. It can be created inside the function like how you do. G6 = len(isPrime)

Comment: My eyes are hurting looking at this code. Please fix the indentation.

Comment: BTW, your program is supposed to prompt the user for an integer, which it then passes to the `specialPrime` function. `specialPrime` is _not_ supposed to call the `input` function itself.

Answer (score 3):

First:

> Write a function called specialPrime which takes in an integer as an argument and returns True [or] False

Your function doesn't take an integer as an argument, it takes two arguments that… I'm not sure what they're intended to be, because you ignore them anyway. So, start with that. Also, give it a meaningful name. `isPrime` sounds like a flag that tells you whether a number is prime, or a function that figures out whether a number is prime, not a candidate number that may or may not be prime. So:

```
def specialPrime(number):
```

---

The next part of your code is close, but it's got problems too:

- You're supposed to be testing the value you got as an argument, not some completely different value you got from `input`.
- `if`, `elif`, `for`, and all other "compound statements" in Python need colons.
- `if`, etc., statements with multi-line bodies need those bodies indented.
- What is `x`? You were testing `isPrime`, and suddenly you're testing another variable that you haven't even defined anywhere.
- You `return True` if the number is `== 2`, and also if it's `> 2` but has no divisors between `2` and the number. That means you aren't testing the other condition; you're just assuming it's always true.

So:

```
if number < 2: return False 
elif isPrime == 2:
    pass
for n in range(2, number):
    if number % n ==0:
        return False
```

This can all be improved in multiple ways, but those are the minimal changes to make it make sense as Python code.

---

Next, you're trying to take the length of a number. Numbers don't have lengths. You can take the length of a string representation of a number:

```
digits = len(str(number**2)) 
if digits > 6:
```

… or you can do arithmetic to test the number of digits:

```
square = number**2
if square > 999999:
```

Also, notice the names `digits` and `square`, which tell you that it's a count of digits, or a square of a number, instead of `G6`, which tells you that it's a group of the 6 major EU countries.

Either way, you then have some of the same problems from the first block with colons and indents again, which you need to fix the same way.

---

Finally:

> Write a program which prompts the user to type in an integer and uses you specialPrime function to determine whether or not the integer is special.

There's nothing about a `while True`-type loop here—it's a reasonable extension to the program, but get the basics working first.

So you need to prompt the user to type in an integer. *Here* is where you use `input`:

```
number = input('Enter a number:')
```

But the result of `input` is a string. If the user types `23`, what you get is the string `'23'`. So, you need to call `int` to convert it:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number:'))
```

Now you have to call your function:

```
if specialPrime(number):
```

And again, you have some of the same errors with colons and indents that you need to fix.

---

After all of those fixes, the code will run. If there are no logic errors in your tests, it will give the right answer. If there are… well, you can debug it from there.

Comment: Thank you!!!    

This was final answer and it runs well! 

def specialPrime(isPrime):
    if len(str(isPrime**2)) > 6:
        return False
    if (isPrime < 2):
        return False 
    else:
        for i in range(2, isPrime):
            if isPrime % i ==0:
                return False
        return True
    
isPrime= int(input('Enter a number:'))
if specialPrime(isPrime):
    print( isPrime, ' is a special prime number')
else:
    print( isPrime, ' is not a special prime')

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code to use a couple of helper functions for each of the two requirements of **`special_prime(x)`**:

```
def squared_less_than_six_digits(x):
  return len(str(x**2)) < 6

def is_prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    return False
  else:
    for n in range(2, x):
      if x % n == 0:
        return False
    return True

def special_prime(x):
  return is_prime(x) and squared_less_than_six_digits(x)

def main():
  user_input = 0
  while True:
    try:
      user_input = int(input("Please enter an integer:"))       
    except ValueError:
      print("Error: You did not enter a integer. Please try again.")
      continue
    else:
      print("You entered the integer {}. Its square is {}.".format(user_input, user_input**2))
      break
  if special_prime(user_input):
    print("It is a special prime.")
  else:
    print("It is not a special prime.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Try the above code out **[here!](https://repl.it/repls/BusyCulturedStatistic)**

**Testing:**

- Prime number whose square is less than six digits:

  ```
  Please enter an integer: 2
  You entered the integer 2. Its square is 4.
  It is a special prime.
  ```
- Prime number whose square is greater than or equal to six digits:

  ```
  Please enter an integer: 317
  You entered the integer 317. Its square is 100489.
  It is not a special prime.
  ```
- Nonprime number whose square is less than six digits:

  ```
  Please enter an integer: 1
  You entered the integer 1. Its square is 1.
  It is not a special prime.
  ```
- Nonprime number whose square is greater than or equal to six digits:

  ```
  Please enter an integer: 318
  You entered the integer 318. Its square is 101124.
  It is not a special prime.
  ```